# Can Entity Framework Core run non-query calls?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Unfortunately my EF application has to call stored procedures I am unable to change. While this is not ideal I can normally get around it. However, I have a stored proc that does return anything. How does EF core deal with this? I know in previous versions you could run ExecuteNonQuery but I haven't been able to find anything similar in EF Core.

I normally run my queries through a helper as such, where T is a class that maps to a return type EF can serialize to:

```
context.Set<T>()
.AsNoTracking()
.FromSql(query, args)
.ToListAsync();
```

However it looks like Set always requires a type as does .Query. Nothing else I've seen off of context would allow you to make a non-queryable call. Am I missing something?

I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: 1.2.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [DbContext.DatabaseExecuteSqlCommand method](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#database.executesqlcommand)

```
using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
    var commandText = "INSERT Categories (CategoryName) VALUES (@CategoryName)";
    var name = new SqlParameter("@CategoryName", "Test");
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, name);
}
```

Or you can revert to [ADO.NET calls off the Context](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#ado.net-via-the-context.database-property):

```
using (var context = new SampleContext())
using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "DELETE From Table1";
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for this. I needed to add the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package to my project to get this to work.

Comment: The methods I outlined above are not dependant on Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational. You must have needed it for something else in your project.