# Disable and enable table triggers in EF core in .NetCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

I would like to delete few rows from a table through EF core. Table has a trigger on it which does not allow deletes but adds a date to a deleted column.

Is there a way in EF core to disable trigger, then call Removeand then enable trigger back again on again after saving changes.

Repository Function

```
//Disable Trigger on Department Table

context.Department.Remove(dept);
context.SaveChanges();

//Enable Trigger
```

How do I manipulate triggers in EF core inside the code?

Comment: I think the accepted answer over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42320808/29353 is more relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core does not support triggers. You need to write custom SQL query to achieve this.

[Here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql) you can find how to run custom query with EF core.

Take a look at below stackoverflow question to drop and create a trigger.

[Creating a Trigger with ExecuteSqlCommand() Throws "Incorrect syntax near the word 'TRIGGER'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675464/creating-a-trigger-with-executesqlcommand-throws-incorrect-syntax-near-the-wo)